# REST service resource naming

Tags: rest

I'm designing a new REST API endpoints and have a doubts about API urls.

For example I have a `Product` entity and corresponding `/products` API.

In order to GET a specific product, everything is clear - I have to use something similar to:

```
GET /products/{productId}
```

in order to create a new one everything is clear too:

```
POST /products with a product details in the HTTP request body
```

but how to deal with product update ?

There is two options which I can see right now:

```
PUT /products/{productId} with a new product details in the HTTP request body
```

or

```
PUT /products with a {productId} and new product details in the HTTP request body
```

the same question for product delete.

What is the best practice here in order to send `{productId}` to server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **PUT /products/{id}** to update the product.
In the Body you should send the ressource or the changes.

> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the
>   supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing
>   resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified
>   version of the one residing on the origin server.

Reference [HTTP-Methods](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)